# R studio time difference in mm/dd/yy hh:mm format

Tags: r

I have tried many commands to find the time duration from all related commands considering the POSTX format, etc. however Rstudio keeps on outputting error messages. The examples state that a "-" works.
For example I have the two columns in a data frame.

And tried to find the time duration, with  commands such as.
[image of code and output from parsed time](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tCWt.png)

And calculating from the original data frame
[image of code and output from original data frame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gf42l.png)

```
> dput(file1[, c("V8", "V9")])

structure(list(V8 = structure(1:19, .Label = c("4/6/2018 14:39", 
"4/6/2018 15:04", "4/6/2018 15:09", "4/6/2018 15:28", "4/6/2018 15:56", 
"4/6/2018 16:02", "4/6/2018 16:07", "4/6/2018 16:10", "4/6/2018 16:11", 
"4/6/2018 16:27", "4/6/2018 16:41", "4/6/2018 16:43", "4/6/2018 16:57", 
"4/6/2018 17:13", "4/6/2018 17:17", "4/6/2018 17:30", "4/6/2018 17:38", 
"4/6/2018 17:47", "4/6/2018 17:52"), class = "factor"), V9 = structure(c(1L, 
3L, 2L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 9L, 7L, 12L, 19L, 16L, 11L, 13L, 10L, 
14L, 17L, 18L, 15L), .Label = c("4/6/2018 15:00", "4/6/2018 15:26", 
"4/6/2018 15:32", "4/6/2018 16:01", "4/6/2018 16:10", "4/6/2018 16:12", 
"4/6/2018 16:18", "4/6/2018 16:35", "4/6/2018 16:46", "4/6/2018 17:24", 
"4/6/2018 17:37", "4/6/2018 17:38", "4/6/2018 17:46", "4/6/2018 18:24", 
"4/6/2018 18:46", "4/6/2018 19:21", "4/6/2018 20:14", "4/6/2018 20:35", 
"4/6/2018 21:44"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V8", "V9"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-19L))
```

Comment: Please share some sample data. Don't post screenshots, use e.g. `dput`.

Comment: Can you post sample data? Please edit the question with the output of `dput(file1[, c("V8", "V9")])`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice those two variables are factors, not dates (or even characters/strings).  Convert them to strings, and then to date-times.

```
ds$V8 <- strptime(as.character(ds$V8), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
ds$V9 <- strptime(as.character(ds$V9), format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
difftime(ds$V9,  ds$V8, units="secs")
```

Result:

```
Time differences in secs
 [1]  1260  1680  1020  1980  2340   480   300  2160   420  4260 18180  9480
[13]  2400  1980   420  3240  9360 10080  3240
```

Note, thanks for following @Maurits Evers's and @Rui Barradas's advice and using `dput()`.  Ideally those error messages are also represented as text, and not screenshots.